# Mongoose Saving All Updates Apart From One

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Mongo database which uses the following Schema:

```
const userSchema = {
    first_login: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    last_login: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    provider_use_count: {
        logins: {
            type: Object,
            required: true
        }
    },
    total_login_count: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        default: 0
    },
    login_hours: [
        {
            type: Number,
            required: true
        }
    ],
    playlists: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Playlist'
        }
    ],
    genres: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Genre'
        }
    ],
    artists: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Artist'
        }
    ],
    auth_providers: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Provider'
        }
    ],
    platform_ids: [
        {
            type: Object,
            required: true,
        }
    ]
}
```

I am updating it with the following function, which is in a class:

```
    async updateUser(user, playlists, currentProvider) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            // Add one to the use count for the current provider
            user.provider_use_count.logins[currentProvider]++;
            user.total_login_count++;
            user.last_login = new Date();
            user.login_hours.push((new Date()).getHours() + 1);

            return user.save((err, doc) => {
                if(err){
                    return reject(err);
                 } else {
                    console.log(doc);
                    return resolve(doc);
                 }
            });
        });
    }
```

However, when I use the `.save()` function it is not storing the updated value for `provider_use_count.logins`. I have tried everything I can think of: using `++`, copying the object and then incrementing it, getting a variable of the current count and then saving it, removing the required field from the Schema, using `+ 1`, using `+= 1`, using an array which houses an object that has a field for count and provider.

I am out of ideas as the save function clearly works -- It saves all other updates. I feel like this could be due to the Schema and it is something which I am either just overlooking or haven't experienced before.

EDIT:

The exact field which is not being saved is: 
`user.provider_use_count.logins[currentProvider]++;`

Also, I am not relying on the `console.log(doc)` block, I have checked in Atlas and it seems that field just remains at `0` while all others update.

As I have not implemented any other auth providers so the field in question should be identical to `total_login_count`

An example of the `user` object which is passed to the function is as follows:

```
{
  total_login_count: 7,
  login_hours: [
    20, 20, 20, 20,
    21, 21, 20, 20
  ],
  playlists: [],
  genres: [],
  artists: [],
  auth_providers: [],
  platform_ids: [ { provider: 'spotify', id: 'makingstuffs' } ],
  _id: 5dadfe7c9a25cc0c6a4d387c,
  first_login: 2019-10-21T18:52:44.814Z,
  last_login: 2019-10-21T19:23:30.580Z,
  provider_use_count: { logins: { spotify: 0 } },
  __v: 7
}
```

Comment: the last part of the `updateUser()` looks strange. you would need the else statement since you are closing with `;`  also you have the `console.log()` in there so there might be an error there. Also, what isn't being saved? What part? could you provide a little but more context?

Comment: I put the return statement into an if/else block but that doesn't seem to have helped. The exact bit which is not being saved is: 
`user.provider_use_count.logins[currentProvider]++;` What did you mean about close with the `;`?

Comment: whats a log of `user`? are you passing in the correct property? It looks, ok, but I haven't user mongoose in a while.

Comment: I just added an example log from the user object which is passed to the function. It is a mongoDB document which has been picked from the DB. The empty arrays will be populated with IDs relating to documents in the relevant collections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the fact that mongoose has issues with saving mixed data types as they are considered `schema-less`. This means that you have to make a call to `person.markModified('name_of_the_update_field')` prior to calling the `.save()` function.

My `updateUser()` function now looks as follows:

```
    async updateUser(user, playlists, currentProvider) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            // Add one to the use count for the current provider
            user.provider_use_count.logins[currentProvider]++;
            user.markModified('provider_use_count');
            user.total_login_count++;
            user.last_login = new Date();
            user.login_hours.push((new Date()).getHours());

            return user.save((err, doc) => {
                if(err)
                    return reject(err);
                return resolve(doc);
            });
        });
    }
```